# how to know all true in prolog

Tags: prolog, negation

Just started to learn Prolog, and cannot figure out how to get the result which involves "all true", for example:

```
preAction(4, 3).
preAction(4, 2).
preAction(2, 1).

action(4).
action(2).
action(1).

takeAction(X) :-
   action(X),
   preAction(X, Y),
   action(Y).
```

The expected result is 2, because `action(2)` and `action(1)` all true. 
But current result is 4 and 2. However the `preAction` of 4 is (3,2) and there is no `action(3)`. This is not what I want.

If I tried to use negation, since 4's preAction is provable, still cannot figure out how to do it. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @IMolly:1 may be a solution too.

Comment: `preAction` "of" 4 is not `(3,2)`. It's either `3` or `2`. And `action` is not `2` and `1`, but `2` **or** `1`.

Comment: so, if I need to get the result of the actions that all preActions taken, how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You add another condition to your `takeAction/1` predicate which uses negation:

```
takeAction(X) :-
    action(X),
    preAction(X, Y),
    action(Y),
    \+ (preAction(X, Z), \+ action(Z)).
```

The last line indicates that you want to *exclude* cases where `X` is a pre-action of `Z`, but `Z` is not an action (`action(3)` is false).

Answer (score 0):

You test that every preAction(X, Y) has an action(X) :

```
takeAction(X) :- 
   action(X), 
   forall(preAction(X, Y), action(Y)).
```

Comment: thank you! although we are required not to use any "high level function", still very helpful to correct my logical thinking.

Comment: @lMolly It is a very strange requirement, not to use "high level function" in Prolog. Either way, keep in mind that `forall(preAction(X, Y), action(Y))` by definition behaves as `\+ (preAction(X, Y), \+ action(Y))`, which basically is the other solution you got.